# Easyadmin 3 field disabled/read-only

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

is there any chance to disable an field to user using EasyAdmin's implemented fields?

I would like to show to user a boolean value of `isPaid`, but i don't want him to change it, just show him (the payment gateway does this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually all i needed and wanted is this:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    ...
    $isPaid = BooleanField::new('isPaid')->renderAsSwitch(false)->hideOnForm();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 16):

What you are probably looking for is this:

```html
BooleanField::new('isPaid')->setFormTypeOption('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: Thank you. What I was looking for.